# downloading files from URL with ashx

Tags: google-apps-script, ashx

Just started using google scripts and can't seem to find the solution for downloading a file.  Here's the issue:

1. Running a script on 100+ URL's daily
2. Each URL is .ashx that downloads the file automatically
3. The script included downloads a file, but not the file type it should be (.xls)
4. The only workaround is to manually change the file extension in Google Drive to .xls in order to view it correctly

Question: is there anyway to save the file from the .ashx URL as a .xls while running the script?  I'm totally fine doing something totally different but need to be able to download these files as .xls' on download.

Thanks for any sugestions,
Jason

```
function getFileFromURL(fileURL, folder) {


var rc = 404;        
var fileName = "";
var fileSize = 0;

try {
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.test.com/InventoryXLS?viewid=450");
var rc = response.getResponseCode();
} catch (e)
{
// fetch() does not handle unresolved DNS or file not found errors
// We'll treat all unhandled errors as "404 Not Found"
// This catch block simply suppresses the error
debugger;
}

if (rc == 200) {
var fileBlob = response.getBlob()
var folder = DocsList.getFolder("MyFolderNameinDrive");
if (folder != null) {
  var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  fileName = file.getName();
  fileSize = file.getSize();
}
}

var retObj = { "rc":rc, "fileName":fileName, "fileSize":fileSize };
debugger;  // Stop to observe if in debugger
return retObj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without testing on a .ashx file itself, I have no idea if this will work, but a couple of weeks ago the ability to convert a file with apps script was implemented.  [See number 15 on this issue.](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1019)

Then again, you may not wish to convert the file to a Google Sheet.  If so, just leave out the optional parameter that contains `{convert: true}`.  Hopefully, this will still be able to set the name and mimeType of your file correctly. Otherwise, I'll delete this answer and we'll start over!

So perhaps something like:

```
var file = {
  title: 'Converted Spreadsheet',
  mimeType: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
};
file = Drive.Files.insert(file, fileBlob, {
  convert: true
});
```

If you could share a .ashx file, I could do some more testing...